# Seeing Code Coverage for a Single Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, emma

I work on a relatively large project that has thousands of unit tests that takes a "significant" amount of time to run.

Sometime I would like to see the code coverage that a particular unit test gives. Currently I use Eclemma to get code coverage, but this only seems to be able to give me code coverage on the entire project.

Is there a way to get this reduced view?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question correctly. What is the problem with selecting a single unit test class > Context Menu > Coverage as > JUnit Test?

Comment: Not sure if I missed something but I've used bot Cobertura and Emma in Eclipse and it works just fine to run a single test and get the coverage out....

Comment: When I run a single test, it checks the code coverage against the *entire* project. I just want to see the coverage for the classes that were touched by the unit tests.

Comment: What about `Coverage View > View Menu (the dropdown triangle) > Hide unused types`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview)? It can give coverage details pertaining to single unit test in the project. I use it and I love it.

Install the clover plugin on eclipse.

Enable the eclipse add in on the project via eclipse and run the unit tests to see the coverage details.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the correct answer is not to use Clover but to do what @his has recommended.
To run a single JUnit Tests in coverage mode simply right click it and select `Context Menu > Coverage as > JUnit Test`.

To see only the affected classes after the coverage has been recorded select the little triangle in the Coverage View and select "**Hide unused types**".

This will filter the view and shows only packages and projects that hold "touched" classes.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Jasmine.js probably you are looking for something like this for the spec files

xdescribe will eXclude those specs from execution.

fdescribe will first execute those specs. if you have both the fdescribe specs will be executed and reset is ignored